# Uneditable prefab in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a prefab in the middle of the scene that I didn't add it just appeared after I added a script that involves rigidbody2D for basic movement. Despite ticking of everything in the scene to see if it is related, it is still there, changing the actual prefab doesnt effect it in any way and I cant select it by clicking on it, any idea how to solve this?

Deleting the prefab also doesnt get rid of it so maybe it is an unteractable sprite stuck in the middle of the screen the scripts or colliders on it don't do anything

Comment: Can you please give detailed information. A screenshot of the object in the scene (with info panel) would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide more details like screencap, code etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a random instance of a prefab appearing in the scene/game view (usually at the world origin), it's just a Unity bug.

Restarting Unity usually *should* make it disappear.